# what is meaning of sed -e 's|PATH="\(.*\)"|PATH="/opt/man/common/bin:\1"|g' -i /etc/environment line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

what is meaning of following command?

```
sed -e 's|PATH="\(.*\)"|PATH="/opt/man/common/bin:\1"|g' -i /etc/environment
```

Comment: Adding `/opt/man/common/bin` to the beginning of PATH variable value in /etc/environment.

Comment: Replaces `PATH="my_path"` => `PATH="/opt/man/common/bin:my_path"` inline, e.g. replaces the file contents.

Comment: Note that ["please explain this code" questions are categorically too broad to be on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) unless they go into detail about what parts you do and don't understand; what you _tried_ to do to understand its meaning; how the results of that effort still leave things unclear; etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It substitutes all the instances of

```
PATH="somestring"
```

with

```
PATH="/opt/man/common/bin:somestring"
```

in the file `/etc/environment`

In detail

- `s|string1|string2|` substitutes `string1` with `string2`

  - the delimiter (in this case `|`) is defined by the character following the substitute command (`s`). More common is `/`.
  - the flag `g` at the end tells `sed` to substitute all non-overlapping matches (and not only the first one)
  - the `\(` and `\)` define a group (in this case everything between the quotes)
  - the `\1` is a back-reference to the first group
- `-i` is telling `sed` to apply the changes directly in the file (inline) instead of writing to standard output.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments this regular expression is very fragile.

- It will match the string anywhere (not only after a blank or the beginning of a line). It will for example match `CDPATH="string"`
- It will not match strings delimited by `'`. It will not match `PATH='somepath'`.
- It will match strings in comments. For example `# some comment with PATH="" in the text`
- It will match inside other strings, for example `STRING='PATH="somepath"`

Comment: What you said here is correct but it's worth mentioning that the code in question won't ONLY change the setting of the `PATH` variable, it'll change any other line that includes `PATH="..."` so it'll change `CDPATH="..."`, `AWKPATH="..."`, etc. as well as any lines like `FOO='SOMEPATH="stuff"'` and it won't change `PATH='foo'`. So it's fragile at best!